# javascript/jquery responsive tooltip with close button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use tooltip when a textbox on my responsive web page gets focused and tooltip should disappear when on blur.

Anybody tell me which javascript/jquery library is best for this purpose, below are my requirements?

1. Tooltip must be responsive so that on small screens e.g. mobile devices it should appear on proper place.
2. There should me close button on tooltip so that when it create disturbance on mobile devices it should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Options besides Bootstrap**

[Opentip](http://www.opentip.org/index.html) looks pretty light weight, powerful and configurable.

[Tippedjs](http://www.tippedjs.com) looks good and well documented.

[ToolTipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) looks pretty well developed and documented too.

[jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) would certainly fit the bill as well.

**Note of caution**. In general when incorporating libraries like these for a small bit of functionality I find it is good to go with the most widely used, tested and documented choice. Sometimes you can find yourself without answers to a strange bug when you use brand new and undocumented software.

**If Bootstrap is OK**

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) has a well tested and easy to use library of various common [JavaScript enabled view components](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/).

You can find their [tooltips here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

Their JavaScript components usually involved a little extra markup, but the time you save from trying to implement it yourself is very well worth it. For your tool tips:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
```

Notice how they specify the button has a tooltip with the `data-toggle="tooltip"` attribute? The `title="Your tooltip text here"` then becomes the text for your tooltip.

This should fit your requirements as well since it is jQuery enabled.

Comment: thanks @bideowego but i don't want to use Bootstrap for this purpose.

Comment: So is it a requirement that you not use Bootstrap? Are you looking for a pure JavaScript solution?

Comment: @Syed Bootstrap's Tooltip is a jQuery library as you request in your question. You don't need to include all of Bootstrap if you only want to use the tooltip - the JavaScript is available separately, as is the relevant CSS (at least as LESS).

Comment: I am looking for jQuery or pure javascript solution, and there should be no involvement of any other framework.

Comment: @syed when you say pure JavaScript or jQuery, do you mean something like what I have above? Or are you asking for code that will accomplish this without including a script? Are you using a front-end framework already?

Comment: @bideowego, Ah, I found some thing helpful in your modified answer i.e Opentip, Tippedjs, ToolTipster and jQuery UI. can you tell me which of them are best for responsive web pages and can have close button in it? for your information I am already using jQuery UI in my project.

Comment: @syed I don't see any libraries that use close buttons, I only see the tooltips being shown/hidden on hover enter and exit. For mobile tooltips I would have a look at this post: http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/35774

Comment: If this answered your question though @syed, please accept it :)